# Database on Jetpack compose desktop

Tags: database, android-jetpack-compose, desktop, sqldelight

I'm developing with Jetpack Compose Desktop and having a hard time finding any up to date information on what libraries are available for database storage. Room is obviously not an option. I have heard sqldelight is an option but not able to find any resources for setup. Thanks in advance.

Comment: compose is a UI toolkit, it doesn't restricts you in using any DB. if you only target desktop, you can use any JVM database(that doesn't have android dependencies, which I guess Room has). if you're sharing code with other platforms, [here](https://github.com/AAkira/Kotlin-Multiplatform-Libraries#storage) is a list of KMP libraries available.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I use SqlDelight in Desktop app build with Kotlin and Compose UI. Here is a resource might help to you as well:

https://cashapp.github.io/sqldelight/2.0.0/multiplatform_sqlite/

Build.gradle.kts

```kotlin
kotlin {
        jvm {
            jvmToolchain(Deps.JDK)
            withJava()
        }
    
        sourceSets {
            val commonMain by getting {
                dependencies {
                    implementation(Deps.Koin.CORE)
    
                    //Database
                    with(Deps.SQLDelight) {
                        implementation(DRIVER)
                        api(RUNTIME)
                        api(COROUTINE_EXT)
                    }
    
                }
            }
    
            val jvmMain by getting
        }
    }
    
    sqldelight {
        databases {
            create("AppDatabase") {
                packageName.set("com.mobiledevpro.database")
            }
        }
    }
```

```kotlin
    object SQLDelight {
        const val DRIVER = "app.cash.sqldelight:sqlite-driver:${Versions.SQL_DELIGHT}"
        const val RUNTIME = "app.cash.sqldelight:runtime:${Versions.SQL_DELIGHT}"
        const val COROUTINE_EXT = "app.cash.sqldelight:coroutines-extensions:${Versions.SQL_DELIGHT}"
    }
```

Comment: Thanks Dmitri, it looks as though that's for multiplatform and not not Desktop. Were you able to use the same libraries for SqlDelight in Desktop?

Comment: Yes, I was. I use exactly the same. Compose Multiplatform is just a UI framework over the Kotlin Multiplatform.



"app.cash.sqldelight:sqlite-driver:${Versions.SQL_DELIGHT}"
 "app.cash.sqldelight:runtime:${Versions.SQL_DELIGHT}"
"app.cash.sqldelight:coroutines-extensions:${Versions.SQL_DELIGHT}"

Comment: By that I mean specifically a "Compose for Desktop" app, not "Kotlin Multiplatform"? Thanks

Comment: Compose for Desktop is just UI framework built over Kotlin Multiplatform, so you could use SQLDelight